# Java chat- server Application - Problem in forecasting messages to all connected clients? 

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

```
package chatserver;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ChatServer implements Runnable
{
    static ServerSocket server;
    static  Socket sc;
    private static  OutputStream ops;
    private static  InputStream ips;
    private static DataOutputStream dos;
    private static DataInputStream dis;
    private static String conversation ="";
    ChatServer() throws IOException
    {
            server = new ServerSocket(5000);
            System.out.println("Chat Server Started .... " );
            new Thread(this).start();

    }
public void run()
{
 try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            sc =  server.accept();
            ops = sc.getOutputStream();
            ips = sc.getInputStream();
            dos = new DataOutputStream(ops);
            dis = new DataInputStream(ips);
            String st = new String(dis.readUTF());
            conversation  = conversation + "\n"+st;
            System.out.println(conversation);
            send_to_all();
            dos.close();
            ops.close();
            sc.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ie){}
}
private void send_to_all() throws IException
{
    dos.writeUTF(conversation);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
     new ChatServer();
     InetAddress sl = server.getInetAddress();
     System.out.println("Address : "+sl);
}
}
```

Comment: can someone tell me what should i do, to send receiving messages from all clients back to all the clients !! ?? more precisely , what should i have to add to the send_to_all() function ???

Comment: Please edit your question, remove all of its current content, then paste your code back, select it all and use the `{}` button to get proper syntax highlighting. Also describe in the question itself **exactly** what your problem/question is (what errors you get, what precisely is not working, etc.)

Comment: Can u please tell what errors you are getting?

Comment: am not getting errors, actually i want to add some code to this which will help me in sending the messages from all clients to all connected clients...i.e. when ever any user hit enter on his chat window..the message he send should be auto send to all the connected clients.

Comment: Your question should be clearly stated in your question, not in a comment. When you say 'forecasting' do you by any chance mean 'broadcasting'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must (at least) maintain a list of connected clients if you want to be able to send them something.

Don't reinvent the wheel, peek what you need here: **[Building a Java chat server](http://www.cn-java.com/download/data/book/socket_chat.pdf)**

See page 22, class `Server`, method `sendToAll(String message)`

Good luck!